# bug in tag synonyms page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I believe I found a bug while adding a tag synonym.  When I was typing in a search for 'mercedes' I get this result:

[image: tag synonym search]

Not sure if this is normal behavior or if this is a bug.

Comment: I've noted this internally, we're looking into it. (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fixed this, it will be deployed in the next day or two.